# If clause with passive sentences

Tags: passive-voice, conditional-constructions

Which one is correct?

> If you select this mode, no more question **is asked**.
>
> If you select this mode, no more question **will be asked**.

Comment: The ***if-*** clause is irrelevant to the syntax being queried. After ***no more*** you need a plural verb, so it's either *No more **questions are** asked* or *No more **questions will be** asked*, depending on whether you're talking about a "current" or "future" situation (or using Present Tense as a future / "timeless" reference).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your comment. I have a software application which has  some sequential wizards. I would like to say if you select the automatic mode in the first wizard, the application does not ask you any other questions. (In the interactive mode of the tool, it asks some questions from the tester). In this case, which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

> **If you select this mode, no more question is asked.**
>   **If you select this mode, no more question will be asked.**

Both are wrong. *No more* is followed by  a plural noun. You can use either the simple present or the simple future in the probable condition.

**If you beat a dog, you are bitten by the dog**.

**If you beat a dog, you will be bitten by the dog**

The first one is called open conditional or Zero conditional.Here both the if clause and the main clause are in the simple present.The voice does not bring a change in tense.

The second is called probable condition. Here if clause is used in the simple present and the main clause is used in the simple future.

The  meaning of the two sentences is almost the same.
*no more* is followed by a plural noun like no more questions or arguments please.

Here is a link which shows the use of *no more*

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/no-more-not-any-more

The correct answers are:

> **If you select this mode, no more questions are asked.**
>   **If you select this mode, no more questions will be asked.**

The meaning may slightly vary.

Comment: No one here is questioning your knowledge of English. That is beside the point. I concur with AIQ: there have been multiple instances where you just repeat what FumbleFingers says in the comments, adding if anything at all your inaccurate information. You should at least acknowledge FumbleFingers' contributions. If you want to get away from an "egocentric" tendency as you claimed in a now removed comment of yours, there might be a good way to do that. You could use **community wiki** which allows you to not take credit for other people's words. Do give credit where credit is due

Comment: You mean to say if it is deterministic, I should use the first one?